# How to pass vectors to a function in C

Tags: c, function, vector

I wrote a simple C program because I just got started learning how to program.
Here is the main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

float mul(float r[],float o[]){
  o[0] = r[0]*11;
  o[1] = r[1]*22;
  o[2] = r[2]*33;
}
//==============================================================
int main(void){
float r[3];
r[0]=1;r[1]=2;r[2]=3;
float o[3];

o=mul(r,o);

return 0;
}`
```

My goal is to fill vector *o* by using the function *mul*; I am required to keep the definition of the variables as it is; the only thing that I am supposed to modify is the function.
When I run it by typing `gcc main.c` I get an error message like this:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float[3]’ from type ‘float’
o=mul(r,o);
```

And I have no Idea how to fix it. What am I supposed to change in my little code? as far as I learned I should pass to the function the pointers referred to the vectors but it should be the same thing of what I have done since the vector name is the pointer to the vector itself.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In C it's called an "array", not a "vector".
2. You can't assign a value to an array.
3. You have `mul` declared as returning a `float`, but it doesn't return anything - change that to `void`.
4. When you call `mul`, since it doesn't return anything, you don't need the `o=`. Just `mul(r,o)`, will be fine.
5. An array is *not* a pointer. That said, an array does decay into a pointer to its first element in most contexts, including the function call you're using it in. Likewise, the `float r[], float o[]` in your `mul` function signature is just syntactic sugar for `float *r, float *o`.

Comment: is there any way to write it as o=mul(r,o)?

Comment: No, you can never assign a value to an array in C ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
o=mul(r,o);
```

assigns `o` to the return value of the `mul` function. But `mul` has no return value--it has no return statement at all, nor does it need one, because it operates directly on the arrays passed to it. Instead, just declare it `void`:

```
void mul(float r[], float o[]) {
    . . .
```

Then call it without the assignment:

```
mul(r, o);
```